# Is there a way to stagger when multiple Alert Views show up in the same View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uialertview

So I have two different UIAlertViews in the same view controller and both alerts can be triggered at the same time.  When both alerts are triggered, both alerts pop up at the same time, with the alerts being layered on top of each other.  Is there a way to stagger the alerts so that when the first alert comes up, the second alert will not pop up until the user dismisses the first alert?  For my code, this is the format I'm using

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR!"
                                                    message:@"Error message here!"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: you can add `tag` to differentiate the alert views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

create two properties

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIAlertView *visibleAlertView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertView *pendingAlertView;
```

every time when you want to present an alertview from your code make a check

```
UIAlertView *newAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...
if (self.visibleAlertView) {
    self.pendingAlertView = newAlertView;
} else {
    self.visibleAlertView = newAlertView;
    [newAlertView show];
}
```

and finally:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (self.pendingAlertView) {
        UIAlertView *newAlertView = self.pendingAlertView;
        self.pendingAlertView = nil;
        self.visibleAlertView = newAlertView;
        [newAlertView show];
    }
}
```

hope that helps :)

**EDIT**

you could even stack the pending alertviews:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pendingAlertViews;
...
self.pendingAlertViews = [NSMutableArray array];
```

before presenting an alertview:

```
UIAlertView *newAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
if (self.visibleAlertView) {
    [self.pendingAlertViews addObject:newAlertView];
} else {
    self.visibleAlertView = newAlertView;
    [newAlertView show];
}
```

and in dismiss:

```
if (self.pendingAlertViews.count > 0) {
    UIAlertView *av = self.pendingAlertViews.firstObject;
    [self.pendingAlertViews removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    self.visibleAlertView = av;
    [av show];
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: There is an issue with this line of the code for stacking the alert views: `[self.pendingAlertViews addObject:newAlertView];`  It says: No visible @interface for UIAlertView declares the selector addObject.
I found that the first answer worked perfectly fine but the stacking method did not.  Now, the alert views that should show up first do, and then there is a pause before the next alert view comes up.  I think the pause might already be built into the alert views, but I was really only looking for finding a way to make the correct views show up at the right time.  Thanks!

Comment: did you change `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertView *pendingAlertView;` to `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pendingAlertViews;`?

Comment: I actually did not catch that change you made! But, the first method works perfectly fine so that's what I'll stick with for now unless something comes up! Thanks!

Comment: well... the first method is fine if you want to work with a maximum of two alertviews following each other. if there could be more you need to use the second version - and this also works if you set it up as seen above ;)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to work with a maximum of two alert views, so that's why the first one works fine right now.  I have no doubt that the other method works as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a class level variable that indicates an alertView is open. Then before you open one you check that variable and if it's set you don't pop up the second one. Instead you could have it set another variable that indicates the second box should pop up. Then in the - alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method you can pop up the second one if the second variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am pretty late for this but still posting as It might be useful for someone looking for this.

I have created a AQAlertAction subclass for UIAlertAction. You can use it for staggering Alerts, the usage is same as you are using UIAlertAction. All you need to do is import [AQMutiAlertFramework](https://github.com/UpliftX/AQMultiAlertFramework) in your project or you can include class also (Please refer [Sample project](https://github.com/UpliftX/AQMultiAlertTest) for that). Internally It uses binary semaphore for staggering the Alerts until user handle action associated with current alert displayed. Let me know if it works for you.